# How to Display a post is bookmarked or not by Loggedin User in Blade Template View in Laravel Blog App?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on Laravel blog App. I want to display posts is bookmarked by loggedin user or not on blade template view .

On Click of post's bookmark button , Im calling ajax function and that is working correctly.

but when i request to page `/posts` it shows all posts with same color bookmarks 
[image]

but not showing bookmarked posts bookmark button with red color

[image]
 i want to distinguish post on page render if it is bookmared by logged in user or not .

I have 3 tables in mysql database : `users`, `posts`, `bookmarks` table

structure users table : (id,name,email,password,...)

structure posts table : (id,title,body,user_id, ...)

structure bookmarks table : (user_id,post_id,created_at,updated_at)

here is code for showing bookmark icon in blade view

```
    <span class="desktop-post-read-later">                                                          
        @if(Auth::guest())

          <span class="post-read-later" data-type="add" data-id="{{$post->id}}" title="Please login to bookmark this post!">
               <i class="bookmark fa fa-bookmark-o" id="bookmark_{{$post->id}}"></i>
          </span>

        @else
         <span class="post-read-later" data-type="add" data-id="{{$post->id}}">

          @if( ?????   what condition here i have to put ??????)

          <i class="bookmark fa fa-bookmark-o" id="bookmark_{{$post->id}}" style="color:red"></i>

          @else
          <i class="bookmark fa fa-bookmark-o" id="bookmark_{{$post->id}}"></i>
          @endif 
        </span> 
  @endif
```

Comment: I would recommend starting by showing us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer , by adding following method on my `PostsController`

```
function get_user_bookmark_postids(){
    $postsids=[];
    if(Auth::check()){
        $data = DB::table('posts')
        ->join('bookmarks', 'posts.id', '=', 'bookmarks.post_id')
        ->where('bookmarks.user_id', '=',Auth::user()->id)
        ->select('posts.id')
        ->get();
        $plucked = $data->pluck('id');
        $postsids=$plucked->all();
        return $postsids;
    }else{
        $postsids=[];
    }
}

 public function index()
{   
    $bookmarked_posts=$this->get_user_bookmark_postids();
    return view('user.posts.index',compact('bookmarked_posts'));   
}
```

and on blade view

```
<span class="desktop-post-read-later">
       @if(Auth::guest())
           <span class="post-read-later" data-type="add" data-id="{{$post->id}}" title="Please login to bookmark this post!">
           <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
           </span>

        @else

         <span class="post-read-later" data-type="add" data-id="{{$post->id}}">                                                 
         @if(in_array($post->id,$bookmarked_posts))
         <i class="bookmark fa fa-bookmark-o" id="bookmark_{{$post->id}}" style="color:red"></i>
         @else 

         <i class="bookmark fa fa-bookmark-o" id="bookmark_{{$post->id}}"></i>
         @endif 
         </span> 
      @endif   
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Auth::user()` returns the current logged user.

Your table of posts already has a `user_id`. You just have to check if it is the same user_id of the logged user:

`@if($post->user_id == Auth::user()->id)`

--------- edit ----------

So, you have to join with the pivot table to know if the logged user has bookmarked the post:

The raw query:

```
select post.*, bookmarks.id as bookmarked from posts
left join bookmarks on bookmarks.post_id = posts.id and bookmarks.user_id = Auth::user()->id
```

Using the query builder:

```
DB::table('post')->leftJoin('bookmarks', function($join) {
    $join->on('post.id', '=', 'bookmarks.post_id');
    $join->on('bookmarks.user_id', '=', DB::raw(Auth::user()->id);
})->select('post.*', 'bookmarks.id as bookmarked')
->get();
```

Then, use the bookmarked column in your `@if` condition.

Comment: No , By this way i only get  that post is created by logged in user or not , but post is bookmarked or not is come from bookmark table (user_id , post_id)....how can i check this at blade template view ?

Comment: Thanks for reply , i have tried your code  but i got this error :  QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `posts`.*, `bookmarks`.`id` as `bookmarked` from `posts` left join `bookmarks` on `posts`.`id` = `bookmarks`.`post_id` and `bookmarks`.`user_id` = `1`)

Comment: @SaurabhMistry edited again :). The query builder was expecting the user_id as the column name, thus you must use DB::raw

Comment: i appreciate your effort ,your answer inspired me to use join query . i succesfully got my answer.